# I want to load data in dropdownlist from sql table in razor view MVC

Tags: web-services

I haven't tried anything because I am not getting any ideas or you can say logic for it
if that requirement was in ASP.Net then it was easy but I am new to web services that's why I can't think of it properly

kindly help

Comment: How about you start by telling us what and how you would do it asp.net. Then tell what you are trying to do and if you want to do it in web api or asp mvc.

Comment: see I have created an admin controller in that I have passed partial view in which I need to create a drop-down list having a data from the backend